# Partitioning $2^\mathbb N$ into $\mathfrak c$ perfect sets

Tags: general-topology

I heard that it's possible to write the product space $2^\mathbb N=\{0, 1\}^\mathbb N$ as a disjoint union of $\mathfrak c$ perfect sets (closed sets without isolated points). I tried to prove that but I don't know how to start. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $2^\mathbb{N}\cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}\times 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

A full proof is hidden below.

> By splitting $\mathbb{N}$ into two countably infinite sets $A$ and $B$, we have $2^{\mathbb{N}}=2^A\times 2^B\cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}\times 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.  Now for each $x\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, consider the set $\{x\}\times 2^{\mathbb{N}}\subset 2^{\mathbb{N}}\times 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.  Each such set is perfect, there are $\mathfrak{c}$ of them, and they form a partition of $2^{\mathbb{N}}\times 2^{\mathbb{N}}\cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ .